# When this rare message comes?

Tags: support, inquiry

[image]

The brown message... "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" .

Many times I saw a question left for long time, but I rarely see this message, and it is only the second time I got it. What is the criteria when the site generate this message?